# How do I melt or unstack a dataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to melt. This is the input:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
file1  text_0  text_1  text_2        
file2  text_0  text_1  text_2  text_3
file3  text_0
```

This is the output:

```
col1  col2
file1 text_0
file1 text_1
file1 text_2
file2 text_0
file2 text_1
file2 text_2
file2 text_3
file3 text_0
```

Comment: could you check my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was offline, answer was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) first, then filter out empty string by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last remove column `variable`:

```
df1 = (df.melt('col1', var_name='col2')
         .query("value != ''")
         .sort_values('col1')
         .drop('col2', axis=1))

print (df1)
     col1   value
0   file1  text_0
3   file1  text_1
6   file1  text_2
1   file2  text_0
4   file2  text_1
7   file2  text_2
10  file2  text_3
2   file3  text_0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do:

```
new_df = ( df[df.ne('')].melt('col1',value_name = 'col2')
                        .dropna()
                        .drop('variable',axis=1)
                        .sort_values('col1')
                        .reset_index(drop=True) )
```

We can also use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) 
to get rid of the `''`
after converting it to `NaN`

```
new_df = (df[df.notnull()&df.ne('')].set_index('col1')
                                    .stack()
                                    .rename('col2')
                                    .reset_index(level=['col1',0],drop=0))
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
    col1    col2
0  file1  text_0
1  file1  text_1
2  file1  text_2
3  file2  text_0
4  file2  text_1
5  file2  text_2
6  file2  text_3
7  file3  text_0
```

Comment: if I have a df with col1-row1 {file1,file2,file3,etc.} , col2-row1 {} , col3-row1 {text1,text2,text3} . cols are in a set how can I change this df to col1-row1 file1, col1-row2 file2, col1-row3,col2-row1 ' ',col2-row2 ' ',col2-row3 ' ',col3-row1 text1,col3-row2 text2,col3-row3 text3.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I don't know why you stopped accepting my answer, could you explain in detail or ask another question?